# Sampling after groupby on each group in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as below:

```
index   accountid  transdate

0        116490  2018-10-01
1        116490  2018-07-01
2        116490  2018-09-01
3        116490  2018-08-01
4        123033  2018-10-01
5        123033  2018-07-01
6        123033  2018-09-01
7        123033  2018-08-01
8        114175  2018-10-01
9        114175  2018-07-01
10       114175  2018-09-01
11       114175  2018-08-01
12       112962  2018-10-01
13       112962  2018-07-01
14       112962  2018-09-01
15       112962  2018-08-01
```

I am trying to get random number of rows from each group of `accountid`.
For example here each accountid has 4 `transdates`, I am trying to group by on `accountid` and get the least 1 and max 4 rows from each group.

Expected Output:

```
index    accountid  transdate

0        116490 2018-10-01
1        116490 2018-07-01
3        116490 2018-08-01
4        123033 2018-10-01
5        123033 2018-07-01
8        114175 2018-10-01
9        114175 2018-07-01
10       114175 2018-09-01
11       114175 2018-08-01
12       112962 2018-10-01
13       112962 2018-07-01
15       112962 2018-08-01
```

I have been grouping by `accountid` and applying `random.sample` on grouped object but every time it gives back fixed number of rows from each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html) to get a random sample of each category and you can set the number of elements to be randomly distributed in `1 ... min(4, len(category))`:

```
import random

def random_sample(x):
    n = random.randint(1, min(4, len(x)))
    return x.sample(n)

df.groupby("accountid").transdate.apply(random_sample)
# accountid    
# 112962     13    2018-07-01
#            14    2018-09-01
#            15    2018-08-01
# 114175     10    2018-09-01
#            11    2018-08-01
# 116490     2     2018-09-01
#            0     2018-10-01
#            3     2018-08-01
# 123033     5     2018-07-01
#            4     2018-10-01
#            7     2018-08-01
```

Comment: Thank you @Graipher!! Any idea how can the accountid and transdate be put into one data frame with repeting account id values for its own group.

Comment: @PradeepPatil: Try adding a `.reset_index(level=0)` at the end, is that what you mean?